# How to Stop python from ruuning a function automatically

Tags: python

I'm working on my new program and i there is an issue with it that I need your help.

When I run my python code and there is a function like the codes below, it automatically runs it but I wanna stop it from running, what can I do?

```
def hello():
    print("hello world!")
hello()
```

When you run it, it prints `hello world!`, but I want it to get compiled when it was asked for. What can i do?

Comment: python doesn't compile code like C/C++/Java but it directly run code when you start script. If you don't run it then remove last `hello()`

Comment: …then of cause your script will do nothing observable.

Comment: Don't call the function???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to the function so that only the def statement remains:

```
def hello():
    print("hello world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hello():
    print("hello world!")
hello() # <-- This line here calls the function hello
```

Remove the last line if you don't want it to print "hello world!".